# Elastic search - add term dynamically in bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am forming an elastic search query as below. I would like to loop through the values array dynamically and construct the query rather than hardcoding the array members.

```
 var myQuery = q.Bool(bb => bb.Must(fi => fi.Term("_type", "myValue"),
                    fi => fi.Term("tags", values[0]),
                    fi => fi.Term("tags", values[1]),
                    fi => fi.Term("tags", values[2]),
                    fi => fi.Term("tags", values[3]),
                    fi => fi.QueryString(ques => ques.Query(query))));
```

I want to do something like the below, since the number of items in the values array may differ from time to time

```
  var myQuery = q.Bool(bb => bb.Must(fi => fi.Term("_type", "myValue"),
                   foreach(item in Values)
                   {
                     fi => fi.Term("tags", item),
                   }
                    fi => fi.QueryString(ques => ques.Query(query))));
```

Comment: Could you please specify the language used and frameworks if any? I believe that your problem is more linked to one of those than to elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
List<QueryContainer> myDynamicTermQuery = new List<QueryContainer>();

// Start of Logic

myDynamicTermQuery.Add(Query<YourType>.Term("_type", myValue)) 
foreach(item in Values) 
{
  myDynamicTermQuery.Add(Query<YourType>.Term("tags", item)) 
}
myDynamicTermQuery.Add(Query<YourType>.QueryString(ques => ques.Query(query))) 

// End of Logic              

var myQuery = q.Bool(bb => myDynamicTermQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

```
  var myQuery = q.Bool(bb =>bb.Must(fi =>
  {
    var ff = fi.Term("_type", myValue);  
    ff = ssTerms.Aggregate(ff, (current, term) => current & fi.Term("tags", term));
    ff &= fi.QueryString(ques => ques.Query(query));
    return ff;
  });
```